# JQUERY TABLA CON .EACH()

Tags: jquery

Tomar los valores de la columna 1 y columna, realizar la operación y poner el resultado en la columna de resultado, a fuerzas tengo que usar el método **.each()**

[image: Asi es la tabla]

***index.html:***

```
<table id="operaciones">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Columna 1</th>
                            <th>Signo</th>
                            <th>Columna 2</th>
                            <th>Igual</th>
                            <th>Resultado</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                  <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>15</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td>=</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td>*</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>=</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

***JQuery:***

Function Proyecto(){

```
$('#operaciones tr').each(function(){

    });
}
```

Comment: ¿que es lo que has intentado hasta ahora? ¿En que parte tienes problemas?

Comment: a la hora de como obtengo los valores de las columnas para poder hacer las operaciones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este la solucion para el problema del calculo en la tabla, con este codigo te permite agregar mas filas a la tabla y realizar las cuatro operaciones aritmeticas.

**La explicacion es la siguiente:**

1) Esta linea se ejecuta cuando se termina la carga de la pagina en Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
```

2) Aqui se hace el recorrido el contenido tr para la etiqueta `id="operaciones"`

```
$('#operaciones tr').each(function(index,element){
```

2.1) Declaracion de la variable usadas

```
   // declaracion de variables 
   var valorA=0;
   var valorB=0;
   var expr ='';
   var calculo =0;
```

3) Se toma el contenido del indice de recorrido por $(thid) y se toma el elemento que tiene la columna 0, luego se pide el contenido de ese elemento con text(). Hay que usar parseFloat() para convertir el valor en numero flotante.

```
  valorA= parseFloat($(this).children().eq(0).text()); // tomar valor de col 0
```

4) Lo mismo que se hace en para la columna 0 se aplica en la 2 (para optener los valores numericos)

```
   valorB= parseFloat($(this).children().eq(2).text()); // tomar valor de col 2
```

5) optenemos el signo de la operacion artimetica consultando el contenido de la columna 1

expr=$(this).children().eq(1).text();   // operador aritmetico

6) Aqui se aplica un comando swith case para evaluar que operador tiene la variable expr para saber que calculo realizar (+, - , * , / )

```
 switch (expr) {
            case '+':
                calculo = valorA + valorB;
                break;
            case '-':
               calculo = valorA - valorB;
                break;
            case '*':
                calculo = valorA * valorB;
                break;
            case '/':
                calculo = valorA / valorB;
                break;
            default:
                calculo=null;
        }
```

7) Finalmente se coloca el resultado en la ultima celda de la tabla, se evalua la variable calculo con un if() para verificar que se reciba una operacion correcta y ademas el recorrido comienza con la primera fila por lo que si toma los titulos para calcular su resultado es Errado.

```
   // poner resultado de operacion
   if (calculo == null) {
       console.log('no se calcula');
   } else {
       console.log(calculo);
       $(this).children().eq(4).text(calculo);
   }
```

El codigo ejecutandose;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="operaciones">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Columna 1</th>
                <th>Signo</th>
                <th>Columna 2</th>
                <th>Igual</th>
                <th>Resultado</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>=</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>*</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>=</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            
</tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // funcion para buscar celdas en columna
    $('#operaciones tr').each(function(index,element){
       // console.log($(this).text());
       // console.log(element);
       // declaracion de variables 
       var valorA=0;
       var valorB=0;
       var expr ='';
       var calculo =0;

       valorA= parseFloat($(this).children().eq(0).text()); // tomar valor de col 0
       valorB= parseFloat($(this).children().eq(2).text()); // tomar valor de col 2
       expr=$(this).children().eq(1).text();   // operador aritmetico
       
       switch (expr) {
            case '+':
                calculo = valorA + valorB;
                break;
            case '-':
               calculo = valorA - valorB;
                break;
            case '*':
                calculo = valorA * valorB;
                break;
            case '/':
                calculo = valorA / valorB;
                break;
            default:
                calculo=null;
        }
       
       // poner resultado de operacion
       // $(this).children('td').eq(4).text()= calculo;
       if (calculo == null) {
           console.log('no se calcula');
       } else {
           console.log(calculo);
           $(this).children().eq(4).text(calculo);
       }

    });

  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

A mi me sirvio este para recorrer toda la tabla , lo dejo para quien vea la publicación y le pueda servir

```
 $('#table > tbody  > tr').each(function(index ) { 
    $(this).children("td").each(function (td) {
        console.log( $(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer [answer], reformula tu respuesta basada en la pregunta no en lo que a ti te funciona.

Comment: No respondas si no estas seguro de que ésta sea la respuesta.